# Setting default display properties for objects returned by a Powershell Provider

Tags: c#, powershell, properties

I'm building a Powershell provider in C#. It returns plain-old C# objects for the items in its subtree.

By default all properties appear - in a vertical list - for every item, which is ugly. Therefore I need to specify the display properties, to allow the objects to be properly formatted out of the box.

According to [this](http://windowsitpro.com/blog/how-powershell-formatting-subsystem-works) article and [this](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/windows-powershell-cookbook/9780596528492/ch01s20.html) one, in order to get a subset of properties to appear when `"dir"` is executed, a ".format.ps1xml" file needs to be created in the `$pshome` directory. I've tried to do this exactly as suggested, with entries like this example:

```
<Types>
  <Type>
    <Name>My.Namespace.Provider.Account</Name>
    <Members>
      <MemberSet>
        <Name>PSStandardMembers</Name>
        <Members>
          <PropertySet>
            <Name>DefaultDisplayPropertySet</Name>
            <ReferencedProperties>
              <Name>Name</Name>
            </ReferencedProperties>
          </PropertySet>
        </Members>
      </MemberSet>
    </Members>
  </Type>
...
```

However, this does not make any difference to the output. It's probably a d'oh configuration error, so here are all the questions that come to mind:

1. Does the file have to live in the `$pshome` directory (which is `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0` on my machine)? Can the file live elsewhere? It seems wrong to have to install this in the WindowsPowerShell directory when my .dll can be placed anywhere.
2. What exactly is the file supposed to be named? There's the namespace of my c# provider, the c# type, and then the provider name specified in the `[CmdletProvider]` attribute. I've tried using the provider name followed by `.format.ps1xml` but as mentioned it does not work.
3. The type mentioned in the `Type` section of the xml above is the namespace-qualified type returned by my provider. Is this correct?

Comment: https://youtu.be/U849a17G7Ro?t=37m30s information and examples that might help you